# Accessing Properties within the same project

Tags: vb6

I'm creating a ActiveX control. I've created a bunch of properties in a User Control and now I want to access those properties in the other modules, classes, forms, etc in the same project but I can't seem to find the correct syntax to do so?

Syntaxt I've tried:

```
connectString = user_control_name.DBConnectionString
connectString = Property("DBConnectionString")
connectString = Property(DBConnectionString)
connectString = Property Get ("DBConnectionString")
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a property on an instance of a UserControl on a specific form, you can do:

```
my_form_reference.my_usercontrol_name.my_property = <whatever>
```

If you want to access the instance of a UserControl that is in a UserControl, you will have to pass the reference to the UserControl via a property on the containing UserControl.

I generally recommend you don't pass UserControl references around. It is generally better to wrap up these controls, and not break abstraction.

If you want to access a property on an instance of a UserControl from inside the ActiveX Control project, I would recommend against it. The only way you can do this is by using module-level variables in a `BAS` module. This variable would potentially be accessible from every module in the project. You would have to set the variable in the UserControl_Initialize event of the control. However, I would strongly recommend you not doing this, because this creates an extra reference to your UserControl, which should really only have a reference from the containing Form or UserControl. This extra reference would mean that if the containing Form or UserControl was unloaded, the control would stick around in memory for the lifetime of your application, causing a memory leak. There are ways around this issue by using "weak references". But this is not supported in VB6, requires API hacks, and is prone to causing crashes.

I seriously would suggest you find some other way to do what you want. Perhaps you could explain exactly *why* you have this requirement.

Comment: I'm struggling to make myself clear due to not being that familiar with VB6 terminology. I'm still in the process of developing the ActiveX Control; I've not reached the point of embedding it in another form. When I do, I expect to use the syntax you've outlined to set/get the Properties of the instance of the control. My problem is, the ActiveX Control has a Form, Class Modules, a User Control and Modules. The Properties are defined in the User Control and exposed to the world via a Property Page. But how do I then reference those properties WITHIN the Form, Class Modules, etc.

Comment: By Set var = new whatever, var.property = 59